# how to read webapi request as proper json format to populate object in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

How do I get this web api request payload to be read as a normal json object inside the webapi.  I'm sure I have to adjust the format somehow but I'm not familiar with how to read this and/or switch it to populate a custom object in the webapi.

here is a chrome dev screen to show how its coming over
[image]

here are some fiddler screenshots
[image]

[image]

my api... I'm trying different ways but bottom line is I need it to return a byte array since the going is to download a file.

here is the webapi

```
        [Route("api/excel/DownloadTopdayTrades2/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadTopdayTrades2([FromBody]ListTradeDetailDTO trades)
    {
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the controller that is handling the request?

Comment: I added in my controller

Comment: I have edit my comment below, I think that you are missing the [FromBody] atrribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple solutions, you can read the body of the request and binding directly to a C# class `var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<ClassName>>();` or you can read it to a `dynamic` variable

```
dynamic obj = await Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
var y = obj.trades[0].AccountNumber;
```

EDIT: `public byte[] DownloadTopdayTrades([FromBody]IEnumerable<TradeDetailDTO> trades)` reads the content from the body request!

Comment: I tried your edit but its null. as for dynamic variable example,, I get await must be task

Comment: this comes back null as well...var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<TradeDetailDTO>>();

Comment: I just tried the dynamic obj = await Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>(); and I do in fact get a string back but it looks like a bad format... like there is these "\" that dont belong.

Comment: The problem is that you have an object and inside that object you have the trades property! You have to create a new DTO that has a property trades of type List<TradeDetailDTO > and then the serialization will work!

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure how to do that.. could you give me an example... doesnt have to be exact code

Comment: ```public class MyDTO {
     public List<TradeDetailDTO> trades { get; set; }
}

public byte[] DownloadTopdayTrades([FromBody] MyDTO trades)```

You have to create a new DTO with property trades and then change the action signature!

Comment: so I messed up.  Your way worked, but because I was submitted data in extjs using jsonSubmit: true, a download window was not popping up on successful upload and processing.  So I have to switch to form standardSubmit: true which changed the way the data hit the webapi.  Can you take a look.  I can't seem to make parse the post data like before.  I changed the pictures above so you can see what I see

Comment: Try to read the form date like this `HttpResponseMessage DownloadTopdayTrades2(FormDataCollection formData)`

Comment: first off, I really appreciate all your help on this... so I tried formData.firstordefault().value and that gives me a long string.  can I bother you to help me convert that string to my custom object?  "[{\"AccountNumber\":\"11111111\",\"Quantity\":20,\"bbname\":\"crude\"

Comment: i think I might have figured it out... checking and will come right back

Comment: No problem, dont forget to upvote my answers! :) `var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< MyDTO >(json);` try this way, I am assuming that you are using Newtonsoft Json Library

Comment: solved thanks to your help!!! using FormDatacollection formData as parameter, them formData.First().Value, then jsonconvert.deserializeobject<dynamic>(stringFormat), then toObject<List<TradeDetailDTO>>()